# A vector field is differentiable if and only if the map $X: M \to TM$ is differentiable

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields

Let $X$ be a vector field defined on a manifold $M$. Then $X$ is differentiable if and only if the application $\psi:M\rightarrow TM$ such that $\psi(p)=(p,X_p)$ is differentiable. I have some problems trying to prove this. Any help is welcome.

Comment: What is your definition of differentiability of a vector field $X$?

Comment: Im considering the follow: a vector field $X$ is said to be differentiable if for every $\phi:M\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $X\phi:M\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable.

Comment: Just a quick remark about mathematical English: The word you want is _map_, not _application_. "Application" is an English word, but it means something completely different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I assume that what you mean by a function to be differentiable is $C^{\infty}$, and i would replaced it by the word smooth. You can learn about this proof (and the machinery to understand it) in Lee's Intro to smooth Manifolds 2nd ed, Proposition 8.14. What i have wrote here is basically  detailed version of the author's proof.
>   The tricky part is the $\Rightarrow$ part. As far as i know, we have to prove that the assumption is true locally on any open subset $U \subseteq M$ first by the help of bump function to extend local function, and then prove that $X : M \to TM$ is smooth (as map between manifolds) locally on $U$. You can see the generalization of this characterization of vector fields on general tensor fields in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/722516/prove-the-curvature-tensor-is-a-tensor/2425962#2425962) or in Lee’s fantastic book cited above.

The converse is easier, so lets do this first. Assume $X : M \to TM$ is smooth as a map between manifolds. For any $f \in C^{\infty}(M)$, the map $Xf : M \to \Bbb{R}$ defined as $Xf(p) = X_pf$. For any point $p \in M$, choose a smooth charts $(U,(x^i))$ contain $p$. In this coordinates, the value of $X$ at any point $x \in U$ is $X(x) = X^i(x) \partial_i|_x$.
So
$$
Xf(x) = X(x)f = \bigg(X^i(x) \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\bigg|_x \bigg)f = X^i(x) \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}(x).
$$
Since $X$ is smooth, then $X^i$ is smooth on $U$. It follows that $Xf$ is smooth on $U$. Since the same is true in any neighbourhood of each point, $Xf$ is smooth on $M$.

For the $\Leftarrow$ part, assume that  $Xf : M \to \Bbb{R}$ smooth, whenever $f :M \to \Bbb{R}$ is smooth.

> First we have to show that this assumption implies $Xf : U \to \Bbb{R}$ is smooth for any smooth function $f : U \to \Bbb{R}$ defined on open subset $U \subseteq M$.

Let any $p \in U$ and $V$ be a neighbourhood of $p$ such that $\overline{V} \subseteq U$. Choose a smooth bump function $\psi : M \to \Bbb{R}$, with $\psi \equiv 1$ on $\overline{V}$ and supp $\psi \subseteq U$. Define function $\tilde{f} = \psi f : U \to \Bbb{R}$ as $\tilde{f}(q) = \psi(q)f(q)$. By extend $\tilde{f}$ to $M$ we have $\tilde{f}$ has zero value on $M \smallsetminus \text{supp }\psi$ and
$$
(X\tilde{f})|_V = X(\tilde{f}|_V) = X(\psi f)|_V = X(f|_V) = (Xf)|_V,
$$
hence $Xf$ is smooth on the neighbourhood $V$ of $p$. Because $p \in U$ is arbitrary, we showed that $Xf$ is smooth on some neighbourhood of each point in $U$. Therefore $Xf$ is smooth on $U$.

Next, we will prove that

> If for every open subset $U \subseteq M$ and any smooth function $f : U \to \Bbb{R}$, the function $Xf : U \to \Bbb{R}$ is smooth $\implies X $  is smooth as a map $X : M \to TM$ between manifolds.

To show this, assume that $Xf$ is smooth whenever $f$ is smooth on some open subset. Let $p$ be any point in $M$ and $(U,x^i)$ be any smooth chart contain $p$. Thinking $x^i : U \to \Bbb{R}$ as a smooth function on $U$, we have
$$
Xx^i = X^j \frac{\partial }{\partial x^j} (x^i) = X^i, 
$$ 
which is smooth. Therefore $X|_U = X^i \partial_i$ is smooth. Since $X : M \to TM$ is smooth locally, then $X : M \to TM$ is smooth. This completes the proof.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed proof! It solved my problem.

Comment: @MatheusSilva You’re welcome