# Riemann tensor notation is indeed a tensor (intrinsic)

Tags: differential-geometry

The Riemann notation is defined to be $$R^{\delta}_{\alpha\beta\gamma}=\partial_{\gamma}\Gamma_{\alpha\beta}^{\delta}-\partial_{\beta}\Gamma_{\alpha\gamma}^{\delta}-\Gamma_{\alpha\beta}^{\rho}\Gamma_{\beta\gamma}^{\rho}-\Gamma_{\alpha\gamma}^{\rho}\Gamma_{\rho\beta}^{\delta}.$$
I am asked to give a **intrinsic** proof that $R_{\alpha\beta\gamma}^{\delta}$ is a tensor. No essential difficulty if I do some 'alphabetical' calculation, but I wonder what kind of proof should be regarded as 'intrinsic'?

Comment: intrinsic proof is to define it without any coordinates (i.e define the curvature operator $R(X,Y)Z:= \nabla_X\nabla_YZ-\nabla_Y\nabla_XZ-\nabla_{[X,Y]}Z$, and show this is $C^{\infty}(M)$-multilinear in all the slots), and then show that it has components as you specified.

Comment: Your penultimate term has the wrong indices.

Comment: Any answer would be purely speculative. Who asked you to give an *intrinsic* proof? You should ask this person to explain what the intention is.

Comment: Regarding the comment from @peek-a-boo, you might wanna look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/722516/prove-the-curvature-tensor-is-a-tensor/2425962#2425962). The definition above is clearly depends on coordinate. We can show that the curvature tensor is indeed a tensor in 'physicist way', but I don't think it is sth that you looking for here.